# PHP delete function?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, crud, sql-delete

PHP beginner here, probably bind to this mistake. Got a crud function going on here, trying to get the delete button to work. Users would currently be on the /crud/view.php. It's currently asking "do you want to delete" followed by the screen refreshing and nothing happening.

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){

$uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

require_once('connect.php');
$ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE users_id=$uid ORDER BY Name";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $ReadSql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Motoko</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>    

        <th><strong>Extras</strong></th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        ?>
        <tr> 

            <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a>
</td>
            <td><input type="button" onClick="deleteme(<?php echo 
$r['u_uid']; ?>)" name="Delete" value="Delete"></td>
             </tr>
 <script language="Javascript">
 function deleteme(delid)
 {
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
 window.location.href='delete.php';
 }
 } 
 </script>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>

<?php

}else{

header("Location: http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au"); 

}

?>
```

With the /delete.php being:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){

require_once('connect.php');

$select = "DELETE from contact where id='".$_GET['del_id']."'";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $select) or die($select);
}else{

header("Location: http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au/crud/view.php"); 

}
?>
```

Comment: You don't pass any id to the php side. `window.location.href = 'delete.php?del_id=' +delid; `. Also please use prepared statements here.

Comment: Could you please elaborate :( I'm very slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Search Contact 1.0" onclick="window.location.href='http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au/crud/searchone.php'" />
</form>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Search Contact 2.0" onclick="window.location.href='http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au/crud/search.php'" />
</form>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Motoko</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Company</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Title</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Phone</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Email</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Address</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Extras</strong></th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Name']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Company']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Title']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Phone']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Email']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $r['Address']; ?></td> 
            <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
            <td> <input type="button" onClick="deleteme(<?php echo $r['u_uid']; ?>)" name="Delete" value="Delete">
             </tr>

     <script language="Javascript">
 function deleteme(delid) {
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
   window.location.href='delete.php?del_id='+delid;
 }
 } 
     </script>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
    </body>

    </html>

    <?php

}else{

header("Location: http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au"); 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines

```
<input type="button" onClick="deleteme('<?php echo 
$r['u_uid']; ?>')" name="Delete" value="Delete">


function deleteme(delid){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
         window.location.href='delete.php?del_id='+delid;
    }
}
```

Always preferred to write you php code at top of HTML script

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){
  header("Location: http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au"); 
}

$uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

require_once('connect.php');

$ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE users_id=$uid ORDER BY Name";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $ReadSql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Motoko</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>    
        <th>
          <strong>Extras</strong>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <?php while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ ?>
        <tr> 
          <td>
            <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $r['id'] ?>">Edit</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" onClick="deleteme('<?php echo $r['u_uid']; ?>')" name="Delete" value="Delete">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script language="Javascript">
  function deleteme(delid){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
      window.location.href='delete.php?del_id=delid';
    }
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried the above. Delete button still just refreshes the page with nothing changing :/

Comment: ok try to debug if `$_GET['del_id']` value is coming on `delete.php` page

Comment: I notice you have not started session on the `delete.php` file ,so add `session_start();` at top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Could you try ?

```
$select = "DELETE from contact where id='".$_GET['u_uid']."'";
```

Comment: Tried that. I think because I have --> else{

header("Location: http://motoko.sorainsurance.com.au/crud/view.php"); 

}

it'll just keep 'refreshing' the screen because the delete button is on crud/view.php. But I'm not sure what syntax I have to get rid of/add.

Comment: have you ever tried 
   print_r($_GET['del_id']) or print_r($_GET['u_uid'])
on your else condition ? just to make sure if the program is executing that code ?